# Reference Id in Javascript knowing only part of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this select:

```
<select id="987_country">
```

but I only know that the id ends with "country".

How I reference it (987_country) using:

```
$('#myIdName ')
```

Comment: didn't get it what you want please describe more

Comment: I think OP want to get the element by not knowing the number before country.

Answer (score 3):

Try with [attributeEndsWith](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selector that

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

```
$('[id$=country]')
```

```js
console.log($('[id$=country]')[0].nodeName)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="987_country"></select>
```

Comment: One reason to downvote is that this is obviously a duplicate so should not be answered.

Comment: @Cid Because this question is exact duplicate and should closed instead of answering to it.